# Export Data with Flag on Tradingview chart

Tags: charts, pine-script, trading, technical-indicator

I have manually marked some flag on tradingview chart. I hve a premium account and I can export chart data. I want to include these flags in my export. Does anyone knows how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot export the position of manually drawn objects on the chart.

You can export the value of script plots to a CSV file using the burger menu's *Export chart data...*, so if you have a script like this generating the "Buy" labels, you will get a `1` in your CSV file when the label is plotted:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
plotshape(rising(close, 10), "Buy Signal", shape.labelup, location.belowbar, color.green, text = "Buy", textcolor = color.white)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am more interested in manually drawn objects. any work around other than the pine script thing ?

Comment: Sorry, but other than screen scraping, not that I know of.